# How to automatically find pattern like 'c++' in string using python re module?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

Now I have a list of pattern:

```
patterns = ['php', 'java', 'c++']
```

and I want to match it in another string, say, r'c++ primer'.
I want to use python re module to do it, but the problem is, if I use:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    re.findall(pattern, r'php php java java c++ c++')
```

I will get an error because '+' has special meanning in regular expression.

So how can I fix something like `c++` or `c*` in this situation?

Notice that I have a lot of patterns to match so I don't want to convert everything like `c++` to `c\+\+` manually.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Made an edit to the question that clarified `\+\+` was not what the asker is looking for. But you SHOULD do a Ctrl+H search with "c++" and replace with "c\+\+".

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by Ctrl+H search?

Comment: @Warbean He means, Search & Replace in the editor.

Comment: Can someone with the relevant power please accept my edit to the question? He means he doesn't want to change to "c\+\+".

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, the regular string methods might be enough, so no worrying about making valid regex patterns, e.g: `for p in patterns: print "php php java java c++ c++".count(p)` will show how many times the string occurs, or `for p in patterns: print p in "php php java ..."` will show if the string contains the pattern at all

Comment: @dbr also a good way. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use a character class. Outside of a character class `+` a [special meaning](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) so it is not going to work as is, you need to escape it first: `r'c\+\+'`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[+]{2}', r'c++ primer') 
['++']
```

**Update 1:**

If you've predefined regexes then use `re.escape` on those patterns:

```
>>> patterns = ['php', 'java', 'c++']
>>> for pattern in patterns:
        print re.findall(re.escape(pattern), r'php php java java c++ c++')
...     
['php', 'php']
['java', 'java']
['c++', 'c++']
```

**Update 2:**

```
>>> to_be_escaped = ('c++',)  #patterns that need to be escaped
>>> new_patterns = [re.escape(p) if p in to_be_escaped else p for p in patterns]
>>> for pattern in new_patterns:
        print re.findall(pattern, r'php php java java c++ c++ .net')
...     
['php', 'php']
['java', 'java']
['c++', 'c++']
['.net']
```

Comment: Sorry that is not my situation. I have edit my question to make myself understood. Can you please review it to help me? Thank you.

Comment: That's what I want! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry I have a new problem. I just want to convert 'c++', but not someting like '.net', because '.' is not special in regx. But re.escape will convert '.net' to '\.net', too. Can I choose which to escape and which not? Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for your update! I just solve it by new_pattern = re.sub(r'\+', r'\+', pattern). I think that is more general. Hope you can add it to your post so someone else can see it. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Escape `+` with `\` like this

```
pattern = r'c\+\+'
import re
print re.findall(pattern, r'c++ primer')
```

**Output**

```
['c++']
```

**Edit:**

```
import re
patterns = ['php', 'java', 'c\+\+']
for pattern in patterns:
    print re.findall(pattern, r'php php java java c++ c++')
```

**Output**

```
['php', 'php']
['java', 'java']
['c++', 'c++']
```

Comment: Sorry that is not my situation. I have edit my question to make myself understood, can you please review it to help me? Thank you.

Comment: @Warbean Just change the `patterns` like this `patterns = ['php', 'java', 'c\+\+']`

Comment: Can' solve my problem sill. @Ashwini Chaudhary has solved it. Thank you all the same.^_^

Comment: @Warbean You mean to say that the sample which I have shown will not work?

Comment: Not meaning that. I just don't want to convert 'c++' to 'c\+\+' manually because I have a list of something like 'c++' in hand now, all I want is auto converting. So re.escape('c++') help me.

Comment: This is the raw text in the question: "Notice that I have a lot of patterns to match so I don't want to convert everything like 'c++' to 'c\+\+' manually." The \ characters were eaten up by SO.